# IOS Obj-C ViewController not passing value

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, segue, viewcontroller

I know this question has been asked, but I have read the responses, adopted the fixes and still have an issue somewhere which I can't identify.

I have an IOS app which is similar in nature to email. It has an InboxVC which is a tableVC with a custom prototype cell which upon selection triggers a messageDetailVC.

The issue is that the messageDetailVC is triggered but the values are not being passed to it. I added log messages to evaluate the value in code before getting to Storyboard issues, and the variable being passed (messageID) has a NULL value.

Can someone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong? My code is:

**InboxVC.m (snippet)**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@: Message touched...", LOG_TAG);
    messageDetail *mdvc = [[messageDetail alloc] init];
    mdvc.messageID = @"123456789-1";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mdvc animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@: messageID value is =  %@",LOG_TAG,mdvc.messageID);
    //messageID has valid value here
}
```

**messageDetail.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface messageDetail : UIViewController 
{
    NSString *messageID;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *messageID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *body;
```

**messageDetail.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "messageDetail.h"

static NSString * LOG_TAG = @"messageDetailController";

@implementation messageDetail

@synthesize messageID;
@synthesize body;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    body.text = messageID;
    //debug messages
    NSLog(@"%@:Added messageID as Body text", LOG_TAG);
    NSLog(@"%@:Value of body.text is  = %@", LOG_TAG, body.text);
    NSLog(@"%@:Value of messageID is  = %@", LOG_TAG, messageID);
    //messageID has null value here
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

}
```

**MainStoryboard:**

I have a messageDetail view tied to the messageDetail sub class of UIViewController. There is a segue with identifier "s_msgDetail" from the prototype cell's selection event to the messageDetailVC (show). As I said above the messageDetailVC appears, just not with the body.text being set to the value of "messageID".

Comment: maybe the code in viewDidLoad is being executed before this line:    mdvc.messageID = @"123456789-1";  The proper way to do this is a custom init method that takes whatever input params you want to pass forward.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `messageID` on the wrong instance of your `messageDetail` view controller. Since you are using storyboards, the storyboard is already creating and presenting an instance of `messageDetail` for you. But, in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you are creating a second one and presenting it. (I'm surprised you're not getting a bunch of runtime animation warnings when doing that.)

You should be setting `messageID` in `prepareForSegue:sender:` like this:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"s_msgDetail"]) {
        messageDetail * vc = (messageDetail *) segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        vc.messageID = /* use indexPath to get data from messages collection */;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I didn't get an email that someone responded. I read a lot about prepareForSegue as it seemed to be the right approach, but I did try it and couldn't make it work. I'll give your snippet a try...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `prepareForSegue` to pass value to another view Controller